# Do not create history entries on hash change

Tags: angularjs, hash, html5-history, fullpage.js

I use AngularJs and [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). When you changes slide fullPage.js will change `hash`. In this case Angular will create history entry. How can I prevent creating history entries on hash change?

1. I don't use any router
2. I configured `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Fullpage.js is designed to work in that way.
There's [a topic opened for it on fullPage.js github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/948).

Hopefully it will soon be an option in the plugin.